# How to insert array field in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, loops, laravel-5

This is my second topics

so i am trying to insert array data with input tag.
I am make the tag input with an jquery

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="steps(); return false;" value="Add  steps">

function steps() {
    var idf = document.getElementById("idf").value;
    var stre;
    stre="<p id='srow" + idf + "'><input type='text' class='haha{{ $errors->has('steps') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}' name='steps[]' id='steps' /> <a href='#' style=\"color:#3399FD;\" onclick='hapusElemen(\"#srow" + idf + "\"); return false;'>Hapus</a></p>";
    $("#divHobi").append(stre);
    idf = (idf-1) + 2;
    document.getElementById("idf").value = idf;
}
function hapusElemen(idf) {
    $(idf).remove();
}
```

also this result after input data with dd()

```
array:3 [0 => "banget" 
         1 => "asd"
         2 => "wwww"
]
```

at this case i am trying to input that array to database and that work

this is the code

```
$hitung = $req->steps;
    $hitung2 = count($hitung);
    dd($hitung);

    for ($i=0; $i < $hitung2; $i++) { 
        $user = new TestCase;

        $user->id_test_case = $req->id_test_case;
        $user->id_document = $req->id_document;
        $user->test_scenario = $req->test_scenario;
        $user->post_condition = $req->post_condition;
        $user->pre_condition = $req->pre_condition;
        $user->expected_result = $req->expected_result;
        $user->steps = $req->steps[$i];
        $user->actual_result = $req->actual_result;
        $user->status = $req->status;
        $user->save();

    }
```

but the result is be like

[image: This is result]

and then the expected result that i hope is be like

[image: Expected result]

so is that possible to make it? without the loop?

Comment: Do `$user->steps = $req->steps;` instead. Also, be sure to cast `steps` as an array in your model class. And you will not need the loop.

Comment: u mean this?
 protected $fillable
 at my model ?

Comment: No, that's another thing (that might be useful in your case, but it's another subject). I mean *casting*: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: owh, I got a new lesson. Thanks :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new `TestCase` in every loop; so of course you're going to end up with 3 rows in your table. Get rid of the loop and use `implode()` to set `steps` as a string:

```
$user = new TestCase;

$user->id_test_case = $req->id_test_case;
$user->id_document = $req->id_document;
$user->test_scenario = $req->test_scenario;
$user->post_condition = $req->post_condition;
$user->pre_condition = $req->pre_condition;
$user->expected_result = $req->expected_result;
$user->steps = implode(",", $req->steps);
$user->actual_result = $req->actual_result;
$user->status = $req->status;

$user->save();
```

Now saving an array into a database as a `CSV` value isn't necessarily the best approach, so be aware that you may run into limitations based on that decision. Consider using a pivot approach (`users`, `steps`, `users_steps`) or similar.

Comment: Wow, thanks this work well, I didn't even think of using implode, whatever this works, thank you very much. Also I will remember your suggestion: D

Comment: No problem; and yeah, array usage in a DB is just something to be aware of. Like I said, it may or may not cause issues, but that's dependent on what you want to do with the `steps` column. Cheers!

Comment: :D I hope you get the reciprocal worth it. Thanks :D